# When removing a component from the markup, is there a difference between component.set("v.myFacet", []) and component.destroy()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, aura

If I have a component in my markup that may at some point be deleted (like a modal), it seems I have 2 solutions:

-Set the facet attribute to `[]`

```
myParentComponent.set("v.myFacet", []);
```

-Call the `destroy()` method of this component

```
myComponentToDestroy.destroy();
```

Is there any difference between the 2 solutions, either in terms of speed or memory management ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm),  Component.destroy() is used to avoid the memory leaks for the components which we do not add them as a facet or to the body.

For the components which are added as a facet or to the body, framework takes care of destroying them if they are no longer available in the mark up.

Comment: If you are using facet you may set it to '[]' and the framework will destroy the component for you.